# Add a tint/color to a submit button in IE8 via CSS while retaining "glassy" look?

Tags: html, css, button, internet-explorer-8, stylesheet

I'm writing a web app.  It's only ever going to be used with IE8, so I'm not concerned with the behavior of any other browsers here.

So: I know how to custom-style a button using CSS properties e.g. background-color, border, and so on.  However, when you apply styles that way, the resulting button looks like a blocky table cell, nothing like the nice, glassy-looking button that IE8 renders by default.

Is there some way to add a tint to the nice glass-looking button?  I.e., it looks just like it normally does, but with a red outline instead of blue, and a red highlight on mouse-over?

Or is this something I'm going to have to do by hand with images?  Again, IE8-specific methods are perfectly acceptable.

Thanks!

-dan

Comment: Windows XP may not have glassy buttons depending on the theme used. If you want to retain a glassy look on buttons in XP IE8, just use a background image and you're all set cross-platform.

Comment: @bolt, XP has little effect over the look of web-based buttons.  He's not trying to use CSS to style IE8's look/feel...

Comment: @bpeterson76: IE8's default style for buttons uses Windows' button style, and that's what it looks like he's trying to get at. I'm saying XP doesn't have the glossy style because its default themes don't draw them that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't really a filter that will get you as close to the default in IE, though you can get pretty close using the `button` tag and standard css. It will not look the same in all versions of IE though.

Here's the [filter reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532853%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) though if you want to try other things.

Comment: The filter reference seems to be what I needed.  Not necessarily going to look identical to the default, but should be sufficient.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of browser, one of the quickest, easiest, most widely tested methods for styling buttons via markup is [Jquery UI's button](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/styling_buttons_and_toolbars_with_the_jquery_ui_css_framework/)  It's a matter of adding a few tags to the class element, and you've got a button based on an  link, button, or input field.  For styling, you can handle styling via CSS, or via the very well done ThemeRoller option, where you can control everything from text size to background type via a simple gui interface--and you can change on the back end or even the user end on the blink of an eye, even via drop down.

One caveat, since IE is non-standards compliant, rounded buttons fail gracefully to square--with proper styling.

I realize that you have determined that you can use a proprietary solution for IE, and in your case it might be just fine over the long term.  But in my experience, that's a really dangerous path to follow.  What if the actual long term is longer than your anticipated "long term?"  You're specifying that it's acceptable to be proprietary to a browser that's well behind the accepted standards, is already a version behind, and uses unsupported (by universal standards) solutions to solve problems.  Conceivably, that version is going to get tougher and tougher to find, and if Microsoft holds true to their patterns, once you install IE9 it will effectively render your computer difficult of downgrading.  And, I can't emphasize enough that IE's market share is dropping like a rock, which is scary considering basically 95% of the machines out there have it pre-installed.  All it's going to take is one overzealous IT director with "security in mind" to render your programming efforts moot.  Sorry for the rant, but IE proprietary code has bit me hard more than a few times...

Comment: Reason it's OK in this situation to use a proprietary solution is that this app is going to be used one time over a 3-month period on a single stand-alone system, and then never used again.  Otherwise I'd stick to standards.

Answer (score 1):

I'd have to double-check, but you should be able to use a combination of a background color and use a transparent PNG or GIF as the "background image" to add the highlights.

All things being equal, I've rather embraced the flat, square button - finding ways to make it work well with the design - but then again I've always been a straight line, square edge kind of guy. :)

As others have mentioned, you do want to be mindful (within reason) of what you may have to handle. It's quite possible that before the next re-write you're going to have to deal with IE9 - writing code that works well in IE8 and IE9 would be the most prudent approach.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://www.webdesignerwall.com/demo/css-buttons.html and also http://css3pie.com/.

Combining those you can get nice looking buttons in IE as well..